# Selling pictures

Tags: selling

[My Flickr Account](https://www.flickr.com/photos/146183724@N03/)

Some people have taken interest in my pictures. Now personally, I don't believe my pictures are good enough to be printed.

However, if I were to print my pictures where do you even start with an asking point?

I can get them printed through flickr for like $100 or figure out the conversion method myself and have it printed through another company. I know metallic gloss always looks good (off topic).

How does someone know when they should start printing their photos and how much to ask for them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is essentially a request for business advice.

Comment: it is tagged as selling :/

Comment: How much to charge (for anything) is a purely business decision.  You need to read up on business basics.  As my old economics teacher explained once, summing up a complicated class, *it's worth what you can get for it*.  We have no idea what that could be.

Comment: Your opinion is irrelevant.  If people want to buy them, then they're good enough :-)

Comment: I think the main issue is how much are they worth. I mean, if I pay $100 to have them developed, would someone pay that much? (i mean if they really wanted it, sure). Where is that fine line between "I am stroking my ego" and "this is reasonable"? I'm thinking it would be best to just set up a simple store and let them decide what they want to do instead of me overthinking.

Comment: I actually accidentally speedy closed this one, but given it was already 3/5 for closed, I'm going to leave it closed as dupe unless a reopen starts on it.  I'm not sure the dupe quite covers how to decide if they should start selling and it's a bit different from the ones about if someone is ready to do commercial work for hire, but I'm also not sure what meaningful feedback we can give beyond "if you are comfortable with selling your work and people want to buy it".